# Pass server variable into client side script

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, variables, express

I am running an express application, using EJS as my templating engine.
But I am having difficulties passing a variable from my server into my client script.

I have tried using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, as suggested in other stackoverflow questions.

**Server side code:**

```
       .post(function (req, res) { //Is there a better way to update votes than using post request?
        if (req.body.buttoncolor === 'red') {
            Dilemma.findByIdAndUpdate(dilemmaID, {
                $inc: {
                    red_dilemma_votes: 1
                }
            }, function (err, dilemma) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error updating votes on dilemma in root: ' + err);
                } else {

                    res.render('index', {
                        dilemma: dilemma,
                        buttonclicked: JSON.stringify('red')
                    })

                    console.log(JSON.stringify('red'));
                    console.log('Data from post request in root: ' + dilemma);

                }
            });

        }
```

**Client side code:**

```
<%
if (typeof(buttonclicked) !== "undefined" && buttonclicked){

%>

    <script>
        var buttonclicked = JSON.parse(<%= buttonclicked %>);
        console.log('buttonclicked in script: ' + buttonclicked);
        showResults(<%= buttonclicked %>);

    </script>


    <%}  

%>
```

**This is how the client interprets it:**

```
    <script>
        var buttonclicked = JSON.parse(&#34;red&#34;);
        console.log('buttonclicked in script: ' + buttonclicked);
        showResults(&#34;red&#34;);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ejs.co/#docs):

- `<%=` Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
- `<%-` Outputs the unescaped value into the template

So you have to use `<%-` rather than `<%=` in the template to output unescaped data.

```
<%
if (typeof(buttonclicked) !== "undefined" && buttonclicked){

%>

    <script>
        var buttonclicked = JSON.parse("<%- buttonclicked %>");
        console.log('buttonclicked in script: ' + buttonclicked);
        showResults("<%- buttonclicked %>");

    </script>


    <%}  

%>
```

Comment: Yea, sorry. I removed it right after, because it didn't actually fix it. It fixed the first problem in a series of problems :) Still having difficulties getting the parsing of the variable to work.

Comment: Oh, good luck with solving these then. I personally can't see any other problems in your code though.

Comment: Thanks :) I am getting this [error](https://puu.sh/y2iHJ/de58911911.png)

[here](https://puu.sh/y2iIu/7d07f4bbf8.png). With this code: [client](https://puu.sh/y2iNF/6da6372801.png) & [server](https://puu.sh/y2iN5/9495901338.png)

Comment: Oh yeah now I see. It is `String` on the server but `Object` on client. While my advice using `<%-` was right you also should wrap the json in quotes on client. That should work I guess. Going to edit my answer.

Comment: Or you can even omit `JSON.parse` in the first place, haha.
Just `var x = <%- x %>;`

Comment: Yea, i have been using the past 30 minutes trying to figure out how to put quotation marks around the json. Didn't realise i could actually just do it around the EJS. I have finally entered the function, and now have to debug that. Thank you!